# Looping over dataframe with extracting different columns at each iteration

Tags: python, dataframe, iteration

I am trying to loop over a dataframe df and I would like to extract different columns at each iteration.

say I have  Columns: `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']` in my df

```
column_names=[['A','B'],['A','C','D']]

    for index,row in df:  //lets assume index starts with 0
       row[column_names[index]] // However you can not apply this syntax for rows like you could for a df to get a sub dataframe.
```

What are my options? I have tried itertuples and iterrows but you can not select different columns by passing a list of column names

Thanks

Comment: Please share a sample input of dataframe with expected output for better understanding.

Comment: Also maybe clarify - you want to loop, and do what? Like you said - this approach doesn't work for looping, but works for data frames, potentially you can leverage vectorized processing here...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to loop over columns and retrieving a dataframe would be to invert your loops :

```
for col in column_names:
    for ix in df.index:
        print(df.loc[ix, col])
```

Answer (score 1):

With `iterrows()` you get a tuple with index at 0th position and row at the 1st. You might want to use `iterrows()` as:

```
column_names=[['A',"B"],['A','C','D']]
for row in df.iterrows():
    print(row[1][column_names[row[0]]].to_frame())
```

For a df of ones i.e.:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

You get:

```
A    1.0
B    1.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
A    1.0
C    1.0
D    1.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks this got me closer. row[1][column_names[0] is a Series. I  had to convert it back to a DataFrame (I know dataframe with one entry does not make sense) and use .T to transpose it back to the original format. I guess I need to change my logic. Thanks

Comment: You can do that too! Updated my answer to include that as well using `.to_frame()`